# Should I use 円 or 輪 here?

Tags: translation, words

I am trying to paraphrase Plato's description of Atlantis. He says that there is a centre island surrounded by two rings of land and two of water. He later says that the outer ring of land has an opening at the south to the sea.

I'm not sure whether I should be using 円 or 輪 or even 円形 to describe rings of land and sea and the outer ring with the opening.

My attempts:

アトランティスが二つの円形の陸地と三つの円形の水域がある

or 水に囲まれた内輪と外輪を有する

then 海につながった陸地の外側の円に隙間がありました

Comment: Could it be easier to say that Atlantis is a city surrounded by two moats (堀｛ほり｝）?　I think that word usually implies man made, and doesn't emphasize the two rings of land and two rings of seas, but might get the point across.

Comment: @katatahito that is a good idea but the structure is thought to have been natural not man-made so I'm not sure if saying 二つのはりがある is ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

円 is "circle", so 円形の島 usually just means a round island like this:

[image: image of a round island]

If you want to say ring-shaped, 輪(状) or リング(状) is the correct term. If I understand your description correctly, you can say something like this:

> アトランティスは、中心にある島を2つの{輪状/リング状}の島が取り囲むような形をしている。